# Camunda Modeler form fields organization

Tags: forms, workflow, business-process-management, camunda, camunda-modeler

I wanna to use Camunda Modeler to create a complicated form cards for User Tasks consist about 20-30-50 fields divided in several tabs. Many cards will contain the same fields and fields groups. I wanna to have an ability to create and reuse fields groups or somewhat liked on fields groups. How can organize process with Modeler? What is the appropriate template? Or maybe you can recommend another tool?

I have a variant of template, but it's not clear for me now. The complicated form will be divided into several tabs. For example the card consists in 2 Tabs: Tab1 and Tab2. Then I can suppose that the card with active Tab1 is one state of the card, and the same card with active  Tab2 - the another state. And then I can configure a scenario for each tab and transitions between tabs. Does it look believable?

Comment: You should keep in mind that user tasks in a bpmn process might not be a good solution to implement a wizard-like screen flow. You will have to deal with the problem that after the first task is completed, the second task will wait until a user (which should be the same) picks it.  So i.g. its a better idea to have a complex form for just one user task and model the task accordingly.  So instead of "enter Customer Data"-"Enter Bank information"- .... you have one "Enter data" task which continues only when all tabs are filled.

Comment: @JanGalinski , I agree with you. But my main idea is to give non-developer employees a tool which can helps organize process and form design (definition of a document structure - set of fields) at same time. Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.bpm-guide.de/2012/04/04/pageflow-vs-process-flow-and-ui-mediator-pattern/

Comment: We created a Framework to do exactly that - sadly it is not open source.

Comment: @pme, can you tell me about the project? I promise: I'll not tell anybody!

Comment: I added an answer, let me know if this is what you asked for - or where you need more infos;).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there are no standard solutions of such kind of issue. I'm going to make an integration [form.io](https://form.io) formBuilder into [Camunda modeler](https://camunda.com/products/modeler/) instead standard form constructor. Maybe it looks madly, but I'm sure - it would be working. The formio has angular implementation of the constructor and modeler is based on the [electron](https://electronjs.org/) technologies. There are looks the same, and integration is not imagine as great headache. I hope. But I need a lot of time to do this.

Answer (score 0):

We created our own framework with Scala / Play and Semantic-UI (Here you can use whatever technology you like).

You model the user form in the *Camunda Modeler*, using additional properties to describe the 'special' components, like File Upload, Field Grouping, Number Field, Radio Buttons etc.

We use then Play Templates / Semantic-UI to implement the generic Forms.

So in our implementation we use the defined properties to generate them in the Form.

So for example you can provide a property `width`. This value we use for the Semantic-UI layout which allows widths 1 to 16. So you have a simple possibility to have more than one component in one row.

Comment: Where do you model a user form? Am I understand right: you have one tool for configure form with Play templates, and another tool (Camunda Modeler), in which you describe  fields from form, created with Play template, one more time?

Comment: see my adjusted answer